# Is there an extant implementation of a reverse "AUTO_INCREMENT" in either PostgreSQL or MySQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, primary-key, auto-increment, countdown

Without having to do it manually (which I'm open to implementing if no other options exist), is there a way in either PostgreSQL or MySQL to have an automatic counter/field that **decrements** *instead of* **increments**?

For a variety of reasons in a current application, it would be nice to know how many more entries (from a datatype point of view) can still be added to a table just by looking at the most-recently-added record, rather than subtracting the most recent ID from the max for the datatype.

So, is there an "`AUTO_DECREMENT`" or similar for either system?

Comment: Subtracting is really that difficult?

Comment: @minitech - at a quick glance, it is not possible to know the size of primary key field if it is auto-incrementing, whereas if it decrements, you can know instantly how many are left, the size of the key field, etc

Comment: If you're good with mental subtraction, it is... but isn't that the entire point of programming?

Comment: @minitech - I'm more thinking about API users and such who will be able to read the data but may not be interested in the details

Comment: Speaking about postgresql, with the primary key ID as an integer going backwards, the minimum value would be -2147483648 and not 0, so it wouldn't be easier to recognize at a glance when it's near the bottom than it would be if it was going forward.

Comment: I like the idea but it has also some down sites. If the datatype becomes to small you can not increase it like in the auto_increment solution.

Comment: @Daniel Vérité - not if you use an UNSIGNED :)

Comment: @warren postgresql doesn't have "unsigned", though

Comment: @araqnid - I didn't know they had that limitation

Comment: otoh a sequence can be configured to stop at 1, or 0, or whatever, as shown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to do a bit of manual configuration in PostgreSQL but you can configure a sequence like that:

```
create sequence example_seq
 increment by -1
 minvalue 1
 maxvalue 5
 start with 5;

create table example(
example_id int primary key default nextval('example_seq'),
data text not null
);

alter sequence example_seq owned by example.example_id;
```

I suppose it would be equivalent to create the table with a `serial` column and then alter the auto-generated sequence.

Now if I insert some rows I get example_id counting down from 5. If I try to insert more than 5 rows, I get `nextval: reached minimum value of sequence "example_seq" (1)`

Comment: thanks - this looks like exactly what I'm needing in this case :)